# Locking transaction on mysql table with multi threading

Tags: php, mysql, multithreading

I am using mysql + php for my web application and I am using sql locks to make sure that multiple instances of my php script select different rows from a mysql table.

What I need to ask is, if I am locking few rows of a table using **FOR UPDATE** clause, and the other instance use the same query, which is a simple **select statement with ORDER BY and LIMIT** clause, will the second instance select the next rows skipping the locked rows or will it wait for the first instance transaction to be completed?

I want that it should just skip the rows which are locked and retrieve next set of rows from the table. For example, I have a sql table with users and a column user_LastUpdated with timestamp

My query would be something like

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY user_LastUpdated LIMIT 5 FOR UPDATE
```

If the users table have huge amount of rows, can two instances running the above query return simultaneous results?

Comment: Do you mind sharing what you're trying to do? We might be able to suggest a better design.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. @Samuel You are correct the link you have given is doing the same thing but is this the correct way to do it? I mean keeping a process id for every table on which i might want to do the same thing?